# Reading XML file using XDocument(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

How to read the CountryName and CurrencyName from the following XML using XDocument

```
<CountryCurrencyMapping>    
    <MappingLayer CountryName ="US" CurrencyName="Dollar"></MappingLayer>
    <MappingLayer CountryName ="UK" CurrencyName="Pound"></MappingLayer>
    <MappingLayer CountryName ="Argentina" CurrencyName="Peso"></MappingLayer>    
  </CountryCurrencyMapping>
```

The desired output being

```
CountryName : US CurrencyName:Dollar
CountryName : UK CurrencyName:Pound
CountryName : Argentina CurrencyName:Peso
```

I am using C#3.0 and dotnet framework 3.5

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(YourXmlString,LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
XElement XCountryCurrency= xmldoc.Element("CountryCurrencyMapping");

StringBuilder sbCountry = new StringBuilder("");

foreach (var item in XCountryCurrency.Elements())
{
 sbCountry.Append("CountryName : " +  item.Attribute("CountryName").Value().ToString());
 sbCountry.Append("CurrencyName: " +  item.Attribute("CurrencyName").Value().ToString());
 sbCountry.Append("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
foreach (XElement element in doc.Root.Nodes())
            {
                string h1 = element.Attribute("CountryName").Value;
                string h2 = element.Attribute("CurrencyName").Value;

            }
```

Thanks